# Entropy in Euler equations for compressible flows

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, compressible-flow, shock

In compressible Euler equations, everyone knows the energy equation can be written as
$$
\dfrac{Ds}{Dt} =0
$$
which implies the entropy is constant along the path line.

However, we have shockwave as a weak solution of Euler equation which is not isentropic. It seems to contradict the governing equation.

Comment: so consider the assumptions that are made to solve the equations like Navier Stokes, Euler, Bernoulli etc